# How to attach eventHandler to a component with ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a collaborative ReactJS project and there is a component that Im using like this --

```
<ul>
  <Icon />
  <Icon />
  <Icon />
</ul>
```

The < Icon /> is a common one and I cannot change its code (cannot make it accept extra props). What I want is, when the user clicks on any of these 3 < Icon /> I need to find its index value.

How do I do this? Tried attaching eventHandler to < Icon /> like this --

```
<Icon onClick={this._handleClick} />
```

But it didnt work. I cannot pass the _handleClick as prop and attach it from Icon's code (as I said, its a collaborative project and I dont own that piece of code).

So tried this method --

```
<ul onClick={this._handleClick}>
  <Icon />
  <Icon />
  <Icon />
</ul>
```

And inside _handleClick, I tried getting event.target but its not giving any reference to the < Icon />

Is there any way I can get the index value of the Icon component that gets clicked?

Comment: You'd have to wrap this Icon in your own component.

Comment: The code you posted is incomplete because it may or may not work depending on the value of `this`. Please post a more complete (but still minimal) example that includes how you define the `_handleClick` function.

Comment: If its collaborative, ask for the feature you need. It's a few lines of code to do this cleanly.

Comment: I would agree with @WiredPrairie. Better to do it cleanly within the `Icon` component itself. Otherwise go with what @limelights suggested and make your own `ClickableIcon` component that just wraps the `Icon` and does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You should rely on event propagation like you mentioned. If someone clicks on the `Icon`, that will trigger a click which propagates to your `ul` element.

When you said that `event.target` doesn't reference the `Icon` element, did you expect it to reference the React component? It will reference whatever DOM element that `Icon` component generated. Here's a simple JSBin that does what you want:

http://jsbin.com/qegukehuda/1/edit?js,console,output